# Overriding a value in a iteritems loop

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary

I've created a function for iterating through a multiple level dictionary, and execute a second function `ssocr` that needs four arguments: coord, background, foreground, type (they are the value of my keys). This is my dictionary which is taken from a json file.

[document json](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=75fd844a1a474e8a9573671194a45882)

```
def parse_image(self, d):
    bg = d['background']
    fg = d['foreground']
    results = {}
    for k, v in d['boxes'].iteritems():
        if 'foreground' in d['boxes']:
            myfg = d['boxes']['foreground']
        else:
            myfg = fg
        if k != 'players_home' and k != 'players_opponent':
            results[k] = MyAgonism.ssocr(v['coord'], bg, myfg, v['type'])

    results['players_home'] = {}
    for k, v in d['boxes']['players_home'].iteritems():
        if 'foreground' in d['boxes']['players_home']:
            myfg = d['boxes']['players_home']['foreground']
        else:
            myfg = fg
        if k != 'background' and k != 'foreground':
            for k2, v2 in d['boxes']['players_home'][k].iteritems():
                if k2 != 'fouls':
                    results['players_home'][k] = {}
                    results['players_home'][k][k2] = MyAgonism.ssocr(v2['coord'], bg, myfg, v2['type'])

    return results
```

In the last iteritems I get the correct value just for the `name` key. The `score` key doesn't appear. It looks like `name` override `score` in my `results['players_home']` dictionary

output: `... "player4": {"name": 9}, "player5": {"name": 24} ...`

I would like something like `... "player4": {"name": 9, "score": value}, "player5": {"name": 24, "score": value} ...`

What am I doing wrong? Here is the full code just in case: [Full Code](http://paste.ofcode.org/kzh9dBn3JFDzduTdNuwdUw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be the/a problem:

> ```
>             if k2 != 'fouls':
>                 results['players_home'][k] = {}
> ```

In your loop, each time that `k2` is not `'fouls'`, you create a new empty dict and store that in `results['players_home']`.  That means that any entry previously stored there is no longer accessible.

Comment: Moving that statement outside of the loop it works correctly. Thanks